# sed command behaving differently in Gitlab CI

Tags: sed, gitlab-ci

I have the following line in my .gitlab-ci.yml to edit the README.md:

```yaml
- sed -i '/<!-- START_CLIENT_TABLE -->/,/<!-- END_CLIENT_TABLE -->/{//!d}' README.md
```

My README.md looks like this, and the goal is to delete everything between the two comment tags:

```
# Clients
<!-- START_CLIENT_TABLE -->
test
test2
<!-- END_CLIENT_TABLE -->
```

My Gitlab runner is using the latest docker image provided by Gitlab which itself is based on Alpine Linux and uses the `ash` shell.

Running the command on my local ash shell works fine and the results looks like this:

```
# Clients
<!-- START_CLIENT_TABLE -->
<!-- END_CLIENT_TABLE -->
```

However, when running the command in the CI, the results looks like this:

```
# Clients
<!-- END_CLIENT_TABLE -->
```

The `<!-- START_CLIENT_TABLE -->` comment always gets deleted as well!
I have tried too many iterations of various quotations, delimiters, and escapings to list them all here, but the command is always malfunctioning in the CI.

What could be the cause for the weird behaviour of the `sed` command inside the CI?

Comment: what happens if you start the container and run the command in the container its self?does it give you the same result as the local ash shell

Comment: Thanks for your input. Interestingly, the problem seems to be with the container. Inside the DinD container, the command does not work as expected. So the problem doesn't seem to be the CI directly. However, the question of why still remains. The image I'm using is this one: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker